# Updating an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

My question regards a voting system, and the method I am working on is used to add an appropriate number of votes to each candidate within the election. 
so for instance, if I had 3 candidates in an arraylist; Jack, Michael, James, this method would update their marks. This method belongs to a class named VotingPaper. The fields and constructor for VotingPaper is

```
public class VotingPaper {
private ArrayList<Integer> marks;
public VotingPaper(String s) {
marks = new ArrayList<>();
```

the Candidate class is:

```
public class Candidate { 
// their name 
private String name; 
// their number of votes
private int noOfVotes; 
// their number of first places 
private double noOfWins; 
/** 
* Constructor for objects of class Candidate. 
*/ 
public Candidate(String name) { 
this.name = name; noOfVotes = 0; noOfWins = 0; 
}
```

this is the method i am unsure on how to write:

```
     * Adds the appropriate number of votes to each candidate.
     * The kth number goes to the kth candidate.
     */
    public void updateVoteCounts(ArrayList<Candidate> cs)
    {
       // ?

    }
```

I also have another class named Candidate which has the method

```
 public void addToCount(int n) {
         noOfVotes = noOfVotes + n;
    }
```

I am having troubles understanding ArrayLists and need help calling the second method to help me update the first method, thanks. I hope this was clear.

Comment: Hint: you do not need to update the array list.  You need to perform update operations on the Candidate objects in the array list.

Comment: Homework I presume? What does the Candidate class look like?

Comment: Update the question with that information and is this homework or can the existing code be changed freely?

Comment: So you need a simple for loop then from 0 to the size of the list -1 and then use `get(i)` on both list to get the number of votes and the candidate to update with the number of votes. I base this on the comment to the method which implies that the two lists are of the same size

Answer (score 0):

From the OOP perspective, it's not a good idea to have separate ArrayList marks, and List of candidates to add votes to them. 
If it's the whole context, I would suggest to use `Map<Candidate, Integer>`, iterate through the list of votes and increment the value for each candidate. 
Keep in mind, that the key in Map should be unique and immutable. So as another suggestion, you could use there and CandidateId, or unique Candidate.Name or whatever.

Moreover, if you use multithreading to count votes, use any implementation of ConcurrentMap.